# Some errors and difficulties with Haskell function composition

Tags: haskell

```
f x = x + 3
g x = x * 3
```

```
<interactive>:17:1: error:

    ? Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (a -> c)
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    ? When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall c a. (Num (a -> c), Num c) => a -> c
```

I'm getting an error with function composition operator. Why does it not work? `f x` works, `g x` works, and even `f(g x)` works, but `f.g x` doesn't work.

Comment: The error is not related to the code fragment I think, please post a fragment such that we can replicate the code.

Comment: Please post your complete code. You also might be interested in learning [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 6):

The code `f . g x` doesn't work because it gets parsed as `f . (g x)`. That is, at first `g` is applied to `x`, and then you try to get the composition of `f` with the result of `g x`.

To make this work, you can surround the composition with parentheses `(f . g) x`, or use the `$` operator, which has the lowest priority of all operators and thus can be used to separate things: `f . g $ x`.