# Another trouble about Haskell Function composition operator

Tags: haskell

```
*Main> (negate.abs) -7

<interactive>:26:1: error:
? Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (c -> c)
  (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
? When checking the inferred type
    it :: forall c. (Num (c -> c), Num c) => c -> c
```

Hi, I am the questioner of  [Some errors and difficulties with Haskell function composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49666499/some-errors-and-difficulties-with-haskell-function-composition?noredirect=1#comment86342949_49666499), and now I got another trouble. Why this simple code not works?
Here is not-working code lists:

```
(negate.abs) -7
negate (abs -7)
negate.abs -7

negate.abs $ 7 //only this works
```

with all same error message above.  I couldn't figure it out, so could I get a little help about why it doesn't work and how can I fix it? And also I'd like to understand the meaning of the error message, and why only the last one works. Thank you.

Comment: Because Haskell interprets this `-` as a binary operator, use `(negate . abs) (-7)` instead.

Comment: Now it works. I really appreciate your help:D

Comment: You can also used the `NegativeLiterals` extension to make `-7` interpreted as a single negative literal instead of an operator (unary or binary minus) applied to a positive literal.

Answer (score 9):

If we look at the expression:

```
(negate.abs) -7
```

we see actually a subtraction. Indeed: we subtract `7` from `(negate . abs)`, so for Haskell it looks like you wrote:

```
(negate.abs) - (7)
```

Now in case you perform a subtraction, both operands need to be a `Num` (and both parameters need to have the same type, but that is not relevant here), since `(-)` has type [**`(-) :: Num n => n -> n -> n`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-45-).

The other expressions face the same problem (although of course with different details).

The way to solve it is to let Haskell understand that the `-` is an *unary* minus that is related to `7`, we can do this for instance by using brackets:

```
(negate.abs) (-7)
```

But we could have isolated it in other ways as well, for instance with a `let` statement:

```
let minusseven = -7 in (negate.abs) minusseven
```